# C#, Best 64bit (long) Guid type generator for low collisions. Similar to Guid.NewGuid() but for 64 bits

Tags: c#, guid

I want to use a 64bit identifier similar to how Guids are used.
Whats a good way of doing this? I want to keep collisions low.

```
public static unsafe long GetLongGuid()
{
   unchecked
   {
      fixed (byte* ptr = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray())
         return *((long*)ptr) ^ *((long*)(ptr + 8));
   }
}
```

Should I just take the upper or lower bits instead?

Or is there a better native 64bit unique hash function that's good?

Comment: Not nearly enough bits to do anything similar to Guid.  There's a good one though.  Start at 0 and make the next one 1 higher than the previous one.  Good for 290,000 years when you consume one per microsecond.

Comment: @Hans Passant: that won't work if you have multiple source independently generating them and still want them to be unique. That's what you need a real GUID for. Of course, you're right in saying that can't be done in 64 bits. Bottom line: if you need a GUID, use a GUID. Attempts to invent your own invariably end up on The Daily WTF.

Comment: @Sven, I agree. In my application I want more speed and am willing/capable of dealing with a collision.

Comment: I have started an elaborate exploration of the same problem, with a few specific requirements, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250484/proposal-locally-unique-guid-alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a random number generator instead, such as `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`.

Exactly why you're using unsafe code here, if not for performance, is very unclear to me.

Comment: I felt it might be a little faster.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider is the way to go as the numbers produced have a better distribution and is less likely to collide.

Comment: Take into account the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Counter-intuitively, It takes only 23 people to have a 50% chance of two sharing the same birthday (collision). **Humans tend to underestimate the chance of collisions.** The wiki has a very nice table that shows for x bits and no more than y% chance of a collision, how many values you can generate. E.g. for 32 bits and no more than 0.1% chance of a collision, you can generate 2900 items.